# Segmentation fault with anaconda-built python (gcc 11.x)

Tags: python, anaconda

I have multiple versions of python built via Anaconda and recently encountered a segmentation fault error when launching python. I suspect this may be related to the GCC version used to build python. While python built with GCC 9 and GCC 10 (installed long time ago) works fine, python built with GCC 11 results in a segmentation fault error.

The problem is that the current Anaconda installation appears to install python with GCC 11 only. I've tried creating a new clean environment with python alone and tried reinstalling Anaconda, but no luck. I also tried `conda clean -a`.

How can I make python work with my current Anaconda installation?

Python with segmentation fault:

```
$ ./python
Python 3.8.17 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jun 16 2023, 07:06:00)
[GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Segmentation fault
```

```
$ ./python
Python 3.9.16 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb  1 2023, 21:39:03)
[GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Segmentation fault
```

Python without any issues:

```
$ ./python
Python 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 29 2021, 19:20:46)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

```
$ ./python
Python 3.7.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 26 2021, 06:08:53)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

```
$ ./python
Python 3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 06:04:10)
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

My default GCC version is:

```
$ gcc —version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I created a python environment with a command something like:

```
conda create -n py39 -c conda-forge python=3.9
```